# Can cdktf commands be executed inside python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terraform, subprocess, terraform-cdk

I am using cdktf for provisioning my resources using Python and Terraform. I want to automate this entire process and hence, asking for the "cdktf deploy" to be part of the python code, as below:

```
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack
from imports.azurerm import AzurermProvider, ResourceGroup
import subprocess


class MyStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, ns: str):
        super().__init__(scope, ns)

        # define resources here
        loca="West Europe"
        rg_name="example-rg1"
        tag = {
            "ENV": "Dev",
            "PROJECT": "AZ_TF"
        }
        AzurermProvider(self, "Azurerm", \
                        features={}
                        )

        example_rg = ResourceGroup(self, 'example-rg1', \
                                   name=rg_name,
                                   location = loca,
                                   tags = tag
                                   )

app = App()
name = "cdktf5"
MyStack(app, name)
app.synth()
subprocess.run(["cdktf", "deploy"])
```

However, this does not work as expected, with the following output:

```
⠼ synthesizing...

⠙ synthesizing...

⠇ synthesizing...

⠸ synthesizing...

⠇ synthesizing...

⠦ synthesizing...
```

Needless to say, the resources are not created.

Comment: I guess you asked the same thing here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-cdk/issues/1624

Answer (score 0):

No cdktf commands can not execute within the CDKTF program. You would need a separate python file that runs deploy. The reason is the program you are executing is calling itself, creating an infinite loop. Your cdktf program is invoked as part of the synth step by the CDKTF CLI on plan/apply/synth operations. This means when you start a process from that program you start it again through the CDKTF CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Try
subprocess.run(["cdktf", "deploy", "--skip-synth"])
instead of
subprocess.run(["cdktf", "deploy"])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).